# Ford 2004 coil keeps melting snd catching fire

Tags: ford

I keep having my coils 6 times melt and catching fire and car will not start what could cause that please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What model is the vehicle? Which engine is in it? Is it always the same coil, or different coils? Or all the coils at the same time? How many miles on the Ford?

Comment: When was the last time you changed spark plugs and boots.